# http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android uri is registered but not recognized

Tags: android, xml

With Android Studio Giraffe, my xml file is in error with the uri in red color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="16dp"
     tools:context=".activity_main">
```

with the error uri registered but not recognized.
They are added in the setting > Schemas and DTDs.

Strangely my Androidmanifest.xml uses the same uri without error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

I tried invalidate and rebuild without success.

Can you help me correct the errors?

Have pity on me in your answers, I'm a beginner.